# Here Api - Hazardous materials restrictions

Tags: here-api

How can I set request parameters for these? I can't seem to find any docs explaining this in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question, it's unclear which HERE product/service you are using. In case of Routing REST API, you can find the description by URL https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-type-enumerations.html#resource-type-enumerations__enum-hazardous-good-type-type

Answer (score -1):

Paste into URL bar:

`https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apikey=YOUR_API_KEY&origin=53.122355%2C12.313142&destination=52.088254%2C18.608308&return=polyline%2Csummary%2Cactions%2Cinstructions&transportMode=truck&vehicle[shippedHazardousGoods]=explosive%2Cflammable%2Corganic%2Cradioactive%2CpoisonousInhalation%2Cother%2Cgas%2Ccombustible%2Cpoison%2Ccorrosive%2CharmfulToWater`

Just replace `YOUR_API_KEY`.